# Same default figure position and size independent of screen resolution on different computers

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I work with MATLAB on the right half of the screen, so I want figures to open on the left half of the screen. However, the figure height should be about the size of a default figure, so not the height of the screen. Also, I use MATLAB on different computers with variable screen sizes (pixels), so figure dimensions should depend on the screen size, but produce identical figures on screen. The figure dimensions and position are therefore dependent on the screen resolution, but the code generating the dimensions and position should be independent on it.

I've accomplished this with the code in my answer below, which I thought I'd share for anyone who finds this useful for their own setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default MATLAB current folder can be set in MATLAB's preferences. I've set this to the network folder on all my MATLAB computers, this can also be a cloud folder of a cloud service, e.g. Dropbox. Then I put a file `startup.m` in that folder containing the following code.

```
ss = get(0,'screensize');
b = 7; % border around figures is 7 pixels wide
%TODO different for various operating systems and possibly configurations.
p = 0; % extra padding pixels from left edge of screen

if ispc
    win = feature('getos');
    i = (1:2) + regexp(win,'Windows ','end');
    switch win(i)
        case '10'
            b = 0;
            p = 2;
        otherwise
            % other cases will be added in the future
    end
end

fwp = ss(3)/2-2*b-p; % figure width in pixels
b = b+p;
n = 5;
set(0,'defaultfigureposition',[b ss(4)/n, fwp, ss(4)*(1-2/n)])
clear
```

Now, every time I start MATLAB, it runs this script and it moves the default figures I create to the left half of the screen with a nice size (the axes are just a little wider than they are tall).

The figure's units are normalised, but they can be set to pixels or whatever measure you like as well. I hope someone will find this a useful script for their setup.

EDIT: I've update the script to keep the default figure units: pixels. This is necessary, because apps such as the curve fitting tool (`cftool`) or the Classification Learner (`classificationLearner`) and probably others are bugged with normalised figure units. Their (dialog) windows either don't show up (they are positioned outside your screen area) or are too small or too large.

EDIT 2: I've updated the script for compatibility with Windows 10. The figure windows now have a border of 1 pixel, instead of 7. Also, the figures are padded a bit to the right, because Windows 10 puts them too far to the left. Windows 10 is detected automatically.

TO DO: support additional operating systems (with detection), e.g. Mac, Linux. If you have such a system, please report the following in a comment:

- Open MATLAB and copy paste the resulting string from the `feature getos` command here.
- Position the figure against (not on or over) the left edge of the screen and against (not on or over) the right half of the screen and report the figure's position and outerposition here.